# Updating an attribute in DynamoDB that contains hyphen or dash (-) in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-dynamodb

in dynamoDB I have a table that has attributes that are hyphenated. (e.g. first-name)

Now I want to update them using javascript. 
This is my code so far:

```
//create UpdateExpression and ExpressionAttributeValues
    let updateExpression = "set ";
    let expressionAttributeValues ={};
    if (e.firstName !== null){
        updateExpression = updateExpression + " "+ 'first-name'+" = :f,";
        expressionAttributeValues[":f"] = e.firstName;
    }

    let table = "tableName";
    let bpNumber = e.bpNumber;
    let params = {
        TableName: table,
        Key: {
            "bpNumber": bpNumber
        },
        UpdateExpression: updateExpression,
          ExpressionAttributeValues: expressionAttributeValues,
          ReturnValues:"UPDATED_NEW"

    };

    console.log("Updating the item...");
      docClient.update(params, function(err, data) {
          if (err) {
              console.error("Unable to update item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
          } else {
              console.log("UpdateItem succeeded:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
          }
      });
```

However this throws me this error:

```
Unable to update item. Error JSON: {
  "message": "Invalid UpdateExpression: Syntax error; token: \"-\", near: \"first-name\""
```

Is there any way around this? 
Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When you use attributes that contain reserved words, spaces or special characters you have to use placeholders. Take a look at [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ExpressionPlaceholders.html).

In the `updateExpression` instead of `first-name` you can use, for example, `#fn` placeholder and then define `ExpressionAttributeNames`:

```
ExpressionAttributeNames: {
    "#fn":"first-name"
}
```

Comment: Is there a missing double quote or is  - i.e. `"first-name"` or should it be just `first-name` ?

Comment: @MarcelloRomani you are right, double quote was missing. Edited, thank you :)